# How to put DataStax Enterprise Studio behind SSL?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I understand that you can configure the DSE cluster to be SSL. Once you open up the DSE Studio UI on the browser, can you tell the UI that the cluster is behind an SSL.

But that's not what this question is about. I'm basically asking is there a way to configure the UI itself to be HTTPS?

I believe, if there's ever a place to find this information, best place would be http://docs.datastax.com/en/studio/6.7/studio/configuringStudio.html. But it doesn't discuss that!

**I'm working with DSE v6.7**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As linked documentation says:

> Studio is designed to be used as a **desktop application**. Distributed deployment introduces potential security risks.

It doesn't support configuration of SSL on its own. If you really need to do it, I would recommend to use Nginx in the reverse proxy mode ([doc](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/), [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins)), or something else, like, HAProxy.